# Potential solutions for syncing an org with Person Accounts enabled with another with Person Accounts disabled

Tags: data-loader, person-accounts, sync, etl

I am setting up a new org with the Requirement that Person Accounts are **Disabled**. Ideally, I would like when an Account gets created/edited in the new org, an Account gets created/edited accordingly in a third-party org that has Person Accounts **Enabled**.

Additionally, I would like when a Contact gets created/edited in the new org, a Person Account is created/edited accordingly in the third-party org.

I have looked around and not found anything with any information on this.

- Is this something potentially be done with something like MuleSoft's Salesforce Connector? Or would this be too complex of a transformation?
- Would a custom batch process running Data Loader for Imports/Export be a potential solution?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration has an overview of the options.

Comment: @identigral - a bit late of a reply, but thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone viewing this, I ended up going with a custom .NET Console Application utilizing the Bulk API and REST API where applicable. Running Data Loader via a batch process was too much support overhead, in my opinion - but would be useful for people with less development experience.